# How to get a message from a Laravel Lang file without the current locale?

Tags: laravel

This is how we get message from lang file in Laravel 9.

```
{{__('page.welcome_message')}} // if we show it in blade file.
```

If the current locale is `'en'`, it would fetch the message from `en.json`. In my case, it fetches from `./lang/en/page.php`.

But in some cases, I don't want to fetch the message automatically from set locale's lang file. Means, even if the current locale is `'en'`, I want to fetch message from `./lang/fr/page.php` file.

How can I do this?

Comment: I mean a simple way is to just switch language temporarily I guess? app()->setLocale('fr'); __('my.translation'); app()->setLocale('en');

Comment: If you just want a list of all messages (to use it for custom things), you can also get them using: `dd(app('translator')->getLoader()->load('fr', 'page'));`

Comment: continuing what @Koeno said, you can add the code on top and bottom of blade file so that it will translate to `fr` only on that blade. OR create an if/else only on a particular div element but make sure you return to `en` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set fallback locale (also see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization#configuring-the-locale)) in `config/app.php`:

```php
'fallback_locale' => 'fr'
```

If you want to display translations from French without changing the current locale, you can use this:

```php
__('page.welcome_message', [], 'fr')
```

I do not recommend this: If you want to do something more general and intervene with the `Translator` package, you can define expressions that you can customize with a provider, similar to a singleton. Intend to use the methods as they are intended to work.